General frame for GL satisfying a consistent set
It is a theorem of modal logic that every normal modal logic is sound and strongly complete with respect to some class of general frames.
As such, the provability logic GL is sound and strongly complete with respect to some class of general frames. It is easy to say that for all consistent sets of GL, canonical model induces a general frame (and model based on that frame) which satisfies all of them.
However, is there a simpler example for a general frame (easier to define) which is not a GL-frame such that, for every admissible valuation, every instantiation of Löb's axiom is true in every world but also such that $\{ \Diamond p_0 \} \cup \{ \Box (p_n \rightarrow \Diamond p_{n+1}) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is true in at least one world?
I was thinking about $(\mathbb{N}, <)$, with admissible sets being cofinite and finite, but it doesn't work, I'm thinking about trees next but it seems harder than I thought.
So, in short, I'm trying to find a transitive and irreflexive general frame with at least one infinite chain, but that for all admissible valuations Löb's axiom holds (and that such a frame is "explicitly construced", not just saying that it's a general frame constructed from the canonical model).

No,  my first hunch is that ${ \Diamond p_0 } \cup { \Box (p_n \rightarrow \Diamond p_{n+1}) : n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is not s finite formula (try to write it out) and so the compactness theorem doesn't hold. See Boolos, logic of provability, page 102, to which general theorem were you referring?

More hunches, the problem.is you have an infinte amount of (propositional) variables how can you even make a model where they are all defined ? (And if you add a statement defining the truth value of each variable what then?)

I think the go-to example of a GL-general frame that is not a GL Kripke frame is ($\omega+1$,>), i.e., the reverse order on $\omega+1$, making the bottom point reflexive, and giving it as the topology the Alexandroff compactification of the discrete topology on $\omega$. My other guess would be $(\omega+1,<)$ also with Alexandroff compactification of the discrete topology, but with the top point being irreflexive (here you do have an infinite chain), but I haven't checked whether this would satisfy GL. Such topology is just the finite subsets of $\omega$ and cofinite with the infinite point.

@RodrigoNicolauAlmeida I think, at a first glance, this example works even without making the extra point reflexive (which is nice, since I's be happy to have irreflexivity), I need to write it all out first to see if it works out. Thank you.

I intend the following not as a sought answer, but at least, a contribution to the discussion.
Let us recite some of the chief properties of Gödel-Löb provability logic ($\mathbf{GL}$):

$\mathbf{GL}$ satisfies fixed-point property.
For all frames $F=\langle W, R\rangle$
$$F\Vdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p)\iff R\text{ is transitive and conversely well-founded}$$
$\mathbf{GL}$ is sound on transitive conversely well-founded frames.
$\mathbf{GL}$ is adequate (both sound and complete) for Peano Arithmetic.
$\mathbf{GL}$ does not satisfy strong completeness (because of the failure of compactness; for this notion, see the question For a compact logic, strong completeness follows from weak completeness).
$\mathbf{GL}$ is complete with respect to finite transitive irreflexive frames.

Note that what is at stake here is validity-preservation (on frames) in contrast to truth-preservation (in models). For example, the modal system $\mathbf{T}$ is sound and strongly complete with respect to the class of reflexive frames. Hence, $\mathbf{T}$ is valid on all reflexive frames, conversely, every frame in which $\mathbf{T}$ is valid is reflexive. However, while $\mathbf{T}$ is true in all reflexive models, not every model in which $\mathbf{T}$ is true is reflexive.
Consider an infinite set of formulas $\Gamma$
$$\Gamma= \{\Diamond p_0,\Box(p_0 \rightarrow \Diamond p_1),\Box(p_1 \rightarrow \Diamond p_2),\Box(p_2 \rightarrow \Diamond p_3), \ldots,\Box(p_n \rightarrow \Diamond p_{n+1}), \ldots\}$$
The corresponding frame would need an infinite chain to be satisfied. But each subset of $\Gamma$ is $\mathbf{GL}$-consistent and Löb's axiom holds.

Is the problem not that there is an infinite set of ( propositional) variables  instead of an infinite amound of formulas?

Not many people are interested in provability logic and discussions are rare. So it might be helpful for us if you expand your thoughts into the answers' space, for the comments' space is quite limited.
